# Error in replacing a fragment in a container

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to android app development and I am currently learning the concept of fragments. I have created a fragment container activity (Home_page.java) which by default inflates the Home_pageFragment. Home_pageFragment layout consists of an EditText and a button. On clicking the button the Home_pageFragment should be replaced by the Menu_pageFragment in the same container of the activity. I have written a code for replacing the previous fragment with the new fragment.

Everything compiles except the below line in Home_pageFragment.java

`transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);`

which shows an error under the word 'newfragment' saying:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type found 'com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit.Menu_pageFragment' required 'Android.app.Fragment'
```

Can someone please suggest me a solution for this?

Below is my Home_pageFragment.java in which the sendmessage() method replaces it with Menu_pageFragment on click of a send button in its layout:

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class Home_pageFragment extends Fragment {

    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        // Do something in response to button
// Create fragment and give it an argument specifying the article it should show
        Menu_pageFragment newFragment = new Menu_pageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        //args.putInt(Menu_pageFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

// Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
// and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

// Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();

    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home_page, container, false);
    }

}
```

Below is my Menu_pageFragment.java (has no errors):

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class Menu_pageFragment extends Fragment {


    public Menu_pageFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_page, container, false);
    }


}
```

Here is my home_page.java: (fragment-container activity) (has no errors)

```
package com.technology.computer.mit.ctechmit;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class Home_page extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);
        // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
        Home_pageFragment firstFragment = new Home_pageFragment();
        // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
        // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
        firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, firstFragment).commit();


    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_home_page, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public void openSearch() {

    }

    public void openSettings() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
                openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
                openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
}
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Replace the following line:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

with:

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

What you are using is fragments from the support library as can be seen from your import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

but Android is expecting an instance of the regular Fragment as can be seen from the exception thrown.

> required 'Android.app.Fragment'

so there is a exception as they are incompatible types.

So instead of using getFragmentManager(), you should be using getSupportFragmentManager(). your other option would be to inherit from the regular Fragment class (android.app.fragment) in which case you can keep using getSupportFragmentManager()

**EDIT:** I just noticed that you also need to update FragmentTransaction to use android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction if you want to continue using Fragments from the support library.

Comment: If I replace getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager() then it shows me an error saying "Incompatible types. Required : android.app.FragmentTransaction Found: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the update you need to make to FragmentTransaction

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

with

```
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

You can't import the `Fragment` from the support library and use the native `FragmentManFger`. `Fragment`'s getFragmentManager() in your case returns the support fragment manger

Comment: If I remove getActivity() and use getFragmentManager() alone then it shows me another error saying: "Incompatible types. Required : android.app.FragmentTransaction Found: android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction

Comment: You have the wrong import for the transaction. Import the one from the support library